# How to Enable a JAVA MIDLET to set as StandBy Wallpaper?

Tags: java, netbeans, wallpaper, midlet, standby

I have developed a **Simple Clock App** in **Java midlet** in **Netbeans**.
Now i want to set **Java Midlet** app as **wallpaper** in phone.

There are **two files** in my project.
**AnimationLoopMidlet** : contains `startApp()` function.

**AnimationLoop** : to update the time and draw on screen.
These are my codes.

```
AnimationLoopMidlet.java

package mobileapplication1;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.*;
import javax.microedition.midlet.*;
import java.util.*; 
public class AnimationLoopMIDlet extends MIDlet{

    static AnimationLoopMIDlet obj;

 public AnimationLoopMIDlet()
 {
      AnimationLoopMIDlet.obj=this;
 }

    public void startApp() {
          Display.getDisplay(this).setCurrent(new AnimationLoop());


    }     




    public void pauseApp()
        {
    }


    public void destroyApp(boolean unconditional) {

    }

}
```

**AnimationLoop.java**

```
package mobileapplication1;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.*;
import javax.microedition.midlet.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.game.GameCanvas;





public class AnimationLoop extends GameCanvas implements Runnable{

   boolean running;
     public AnimationLoop()
     {
         super(false);

         start();
     }
     void start()
     {
            Thread t=new Thread(this);
            t.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
            t.start();
     }
     public void run()
     {
         running=true;
         while(running)
         {
             update();
             flushGraphics();
         }
     }









            public void update()
            {
                Graphics g=getGraphics();
                    Date c= new Date(); 
                String s=new String();
                s=""+c;
                g.setColor(0xffffff);
                g.setStrokeStyle(Graphics.SOLID);
                g.fillRect(0,0,240,320);

                g.setColor(0x000000);
                g.setFont(Font.getDefaultFont());

                g.drawString("Day:"+s.substring(0,4),0,14,g.LEFT | g.TOP);
                g.drawString("Month"+s.substring(4,7),0,30,g.LEFT | g.TOP);
                g.drawString("Date:"+s.substring(8,10),0,50,g.LEFT | g.TOP);
                g.drawString("Hour:"+s.substring(11,13),0,70,g.LEFT | g.TOP);
                g.drawString("Minute:"+s.substring(14,16),0,90,g.LEFT | g.TOP);
                g.drawString("Seconds:"+s.substring(17,19),0,120,g.LEFT | g.TOP);
              }      





}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only few JavaME enabled phones offer this option.

(It did become possible with MIDP3.0 though, but since MIDP3.0 never saw daylight, we're still stuck with MIDP2.1).

You can do it with some Sony Ericsson phones by putting the following attribute in the JAD/MANIFEST:

```
SEMC-StandbyApplication: Y
```

This works on devices like Sony Ericsson Aino and Elm and K800.

http://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/code-example-module/create-standby-midlet-for-java-platform-jp-7-phones/